# Facing issue with CONTAINS,JSON_VALUE AND JSON_TEXTCONTAINS while searching text in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a JSON column and I'm trying to do search on this column by using the `CONTAINS` function.

Table1

| JSON_COL |
| --- |
| `{"MarketInfo":"ABCDEFGHE"{"data" : "ABC" "OriginalData": "I"}}` |

```sql
Select *
from   table1
where  CONTAINS(JSON_COL, "I INPATH('/MarketInfo/ABCDEFGHE/OriginalData)')>0)
```

gives me no result

| JSON_COL |
| --- |
| `{"MarketInfo": "ABCDEFGHE"{"data" : "ABC" "OriginalData": "II"}}` |

```sql
Select *
from   table1
where  CONTAINS(JSON_COL, "II INPATH('/MarketInfo/ABCDEFGHE/OriginalData)')>0)
```

gives me correct result.

I checked with `json_textcontains` and `json_value` these functions also having same. Results are correct when searched with `II` but when I search with `I` results are not displayed. Could you please let me know what is the issue here?

Comment: You are missing a comma in each of your JSON in the inner object between the key-value pairs and the `{}` brackets around the `"ABCDEFGHE"` object.

Comment: Also, [`INPATH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/ccref/oracle-text-CONTAINS-query-operators.html#GUID-F78EC75C-55C8-4C79-A744-AE0DB2E1F581) is "to do path searching in XML documents." Why do you expect it would work on JSON documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONTAINS` works on XML data; not JSON data.

> I checked with `json_textcontains` and `json_value` these functions also having same.

There appears to be something strange (possibly a bug, possibly a conversion to a different data type):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  JSON_COL CLOB CHECK (json_col IS JSON)
);

CREATE INDEX json_index   
  ON table1(json_col)   
  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT   
  PARAMETERS ('SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (ON COMMIT)')

INSERT INTO table1 (JSON_COL)
SELECT '{"MarketInfo": {"ABCDEFGHE": {"data": "ABC", "OriginalData": "X"}}}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"MarketInfo": {"ABCDEFGHE": {"data": "ABC", "OriginalData": "I"}}}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{"MarketInfo": {"ABCDEFGHE": {"data": "ABC", "OriginalData": "II"}}}' FROM DUAL;

COMMIT;
```

Then if you do:

```sql
SELECT json_col
FROM   table1
WHERE  JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(json_col, '$.MarketInfo.ABCDEFGHE.OriginalData', 'I')
```

or

```
SELECT json_col
FROM   table1
WHERE  JSON_VALUE(json_col, '$.MarketInfo.ABCDEFGHE.OriginalData') = 'I'
```

or

```sql
SELECT json_col
FROM   table1
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         json_col,
         '$.MarketInfo.ABCDEFGHE'
         COLUMNS (
           OriginalData VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.OriginalData'
         )
       )
WHERE  OriginalData = 'I'
```

Then no rows are output. But substituting `II` or `X` instead of `I` they both return the matching row.

You can get the correct result with an explicit cast to a `VARCHAR2` data type:

```sql
SELECT json_col
FROM   table1
WHERE  CAST(JSON_VALUE(json_col, '$.MarketInfo.ABCDEFGHE.OriginalData') AS VARCHAR2(20)) = 'I'
```

or

```sql
SELECT json_col
FROM   table1
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         json_col,
         '$.MarketInfo.ABCDEFGHE'
         COLUMNS (
           OriginalData VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.OriginalData'
         )
       )
WHERE  CAST(OriginalData AS VARCHAR2(20)) = 'I'
```

Which both output:

> | JSON_COL |
> | --- |
> | {"MarketInfo": {"ABCDEFGHE": {"data": "ABC", "OriginalData": "I"}}} |

But there is no obvious reason why this would be required.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=44375456aae811ebc884119106094e34)*